# How is the line <script src="<%= ... %> "/> turned into a proper line of html?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

In the sample Angular app, [`angular-app`, on GitHub](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app), the `index.html` file [contains the line](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/index.html#L9)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/<%= grunt.config.get('pkg.name') %>.js"></script>
```

When I try to run the project in my webserver, it has a problem with this line and fails to display anything.

Apparently I have to build the project with Grunt to make this work first. But before I, or any future readers, have a chance to deeply learn Grunt, can someone explain how [the Grunt file](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/gruntFile.js) turns this line into what it needs to be?

---

**EDIT**

As per @JBNizet's comment, here's the HTML code and Grunjs code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/<%= grunt.config.get('pkg.name') %>.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/mongolab.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/<%= grunt.config.get('pkg.name') %>.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div ng-include="'header.tpl.html'"></div>
  <div ng-include="'notifications.tpl.html'" class="container-fluid" ng-show="notifications.getCurrent().length"></div>
  <div ng-view class="container-fluid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Grunt file:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-recess');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-html2js');

  // Default task.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint','build','karma:unit']);
  grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean','html2js','concat','recess:build','copy:assets']);
  grunt.registerTask('release', ['clean','html2js','uglify','jshint','karma:unit','concat:index', 'recess:min','copy:assets']);
  grunt.registerTask('test-watch', ['karma:watch']);

  // Print a timestamp (useful for when watching)
  grunt.registerTask('timestamp', function() {
    grunt.log.subhead(Date());
  });

  var karmaConfig = function(configFile, customOptions) {
    var options = { configFile: configFile, keepalive: true };
    var travisOptions = process.env.TRAVIS && { browsers: ['Firefox'], reporters: 'dots' };
    return grunt.util._.extend(options, customOptions, travisOptions);
  };

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    distdir: 'dist',
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    banner:
    '/*! <%= pkg.title || pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>\n' +
    '<%= pkg.homepage ? " * " + pkg.homepage + "\\n" : "" %>' +
    ' * Copyright (c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> <%= pkg.author %>;\n' +
    ' * Licensed <%= _.pluck(pkg.licenses, "type").join(", ") %>\n */\n',
    src: {
      js: ['src/**/*.js'],
      jsTpl: ['<%= distdir %>/templates/**/*.js'],
      specs: ['test/**/*.spec.js'],
      scenarios: ['test/**/*.scenario.js'],
      html: ['src/index.html'],
      tpl: {
        app: ['src/app/**/*.tpl.html'],
        common: ['src/common/**/*.tpl.html']
      },
      less: ['src/less/stylesheet.less'], // recess:build doesn't accept ** in its file patterns
      lessWatch: ['src/less/**/*.less']
    },
    clean: ['<%= distdir %>/*'],
    copy: {
      assets: {
        files: [{ dest: '<%= distdir %>', src : '**', expand: true, cwd: 'src/assets/' }]
      }
    },
    karma: {
      unit: { options: karmaConfig('test/config/unit.js') },
      watch: { options: karmaConfig('test/config/unit.js', { singleRun:false, autoWatch: true}) }
    },
    html2js: {
      app: {
        options: {
          base: 'src/app'
        },
        src: ['<%= src.tpl.app %>'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/templates/app.js',
        module: 'templates.app'
      },
      common: {
        options: {
          base: 'src/common'
        },
        src: ['<%= src.tpl.common %>'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/templates/common.js',
        module: 'templates.common'
      }
    },
    concat:{
      dist:{
        options: {
          banner: "<%= banner %>"
        },
        src:['<%= src.js %>', '<%= src.jsTpl %>'],
        dest:'<%= distdir %>/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
      },
      index: {
        src: ['src/index.html'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/index.html',
        options: {
          process: true
        }
      },
      angular: {
        src:['vendor/angular/angular.js', 'vendor/angular/angular-route.js'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/angular.js'
      },
      mongo: {
        src:['vendor/mongolab/*.js'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/mongolab.js'
      },
      bootstrap: {
        src:['vendor/angular-ui/bootstrap/*.js'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/bootstrap.js'
      },
      jquery: {
        src:['vendor/jquery/*.js'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/jquery.js'
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      dist:{
        options: {
          banner: "<%= banner %>"
        },
        src:['<%= src.js %>' ,'<%= src.jsTpl %>'],
        dest:'<%= distdir %>/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
      },
      angular: {
        src:['<%= concat.angular.src %>'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/angular.js'
      },
      mongo: {
        src:['vendor/mongolab/*.js'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/mongolab.js'
      },
      bootstrap: {
        src:['vendor/angular-ui/bootstrap/*.js'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/bootstrap.js'
      },
      jquery: {
        src:['vendor/jquery/*.js'],
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/jquery.js'
      }
    },
    recess: {
      build: {
        files: {
          '<%= distdir %>/<%= pkg.name %>.css':
          ['<%= src.less %>'] },
        options: {
          compile: true
        }
      },
      min: {
        files: {
          '<%= distdir %>/<%= pkg.name %>.css': ['<%= src.less %>']
        },
        options: {
          compress: true
        }
      }
    },
    watch:{
      all: {
        files:['<%= src.js %>', '<%= src.specs %>', '<%= src.lessWatch %>', '<%= src.tpl.app %>', '<%= src.tpl.common %>', '<%= src.html %>'],
        tasks:['default','timestamp']
      },
      build: {
        files:['<%= src.js %>', '<%= src.specs %>', '<%= src.lessWatch %>', '<%= src.tpl.app %>', '<%= src.tpl.common %>', '<%= src.html %>'],
        tasks:['build','timestamp']
      }
    },
    jshint:{
      files:['gruntFile.js', '<%= src.js %>', '<%= src.jsTpl %>', '<%= src.specs %>', '<%= src.scenarios %>'],
      options:{
        curly:true,
        eqeqeq:true,
        immed:true,
        latedef:true,
        newcap:true,
        noarg:true,
        sub:true,
        boss:true,
        eqnull:true,
        globals:{}
      }
    }
  });

};
```

Comment: The code must be in the question. Not linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index file is parsed, by a grunt task, probably `grunt build`, and the `<%= grunt.config.get('pkg.name') %>` portion is replace with the name of the package.

`grunt.config.get('pkg.name')` is just JavaScript.

Change it to `console.log(grunt.config.get('pkg.name'))` to see what happens.

Specifically, it's the `concat` grunt task that does the templating or what's found in `client/src/index.html`, placing it in client/dist/index.html`.

Comment: Grunt build most likely. I'm just doing it now to see what happens.

Comment: Your concat:index is responsible for this. Have a look at https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat. As Adrian says, it replaces the '<%= grunt.config.get('pkg.name') %>' part and replaces it with the value of the pkg.name from your package.json file.